# Python selenium проверить наличие элемента на веб странице

Tags: python, selenium

мне необходимо проверить что определенный элемент присутствует на веб-странице.

Нахожу элемент следующим образом:

```
Element = driver.find_element_by_id('text')
```

Проверку сделал следующим образом:

```
self.assertTrue("id = text", Element)
```

Но, мне сказали что это не правильно, потому что этот код ничего не проверяет: первый параметр метода это и есть проверка, а второй просто сообщение, которое выводится при падении.

После этого я нашел как проверить наличие элементов следующим методом:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def check_exists_by_id(id):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_id(id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

Теперь я вообще запутался. Скажите пожалуйста, каким методом все таки нужно производить проверку наличия элемента на странице? И все таки, возможно ли это сделать через `assert.True()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC   

pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
```

Ожидает, что в течении 10 секунд данный элемент будет расположен и виден.
Если в течении 10 секунд не найден, кинет ошибку Timeout. Возвращает элемент **как только найден**, но не позднее 10 секунд

У EC много условий нахождения элемента, посмотрите и выберите наиболее нужный для вас